Is it possible to use isaac_ros_cumotion motion planner for bimanual robot?
I want to control baxter robot using isaac_ros_cumotion planner. I am having problems setting it up, so I am wondering if it is even possible to use it out of the box or would there some changes to the code/urdf need to be done.
I have generated baxter.xrdf file using isaac_sim, which defines collision spheres, etc, and have also added tags that are required for cuMotion but aren't generated by the isaac_sim. Spheres generated for the both arms are in the same file. For using it with cuMotion, would I need to have a separate .xrdf file for every arm and then also a  planner node for every arm, or it can be done using single .xrdf file and single cuMotion planning node?
Looking at the xrdf documentation for tool_frame tag, it states that:

cuMotion requires at least one entry and uses the first entry as the “end effector frame” (i.e., the frame for which task space targets will be assigned for generating collision-free trajectories)

so if I have tool_frames: ["left_hand", "right_hand"] in my baxter.xrdf, cuMotion will only be able to plan for left end-effector and not for the right?
